# background image confusion using UINavController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am having trouble explaining this to myself but here is my best attempt.

I have a rootViewController that has a unique background imageView (placed in IB). When the user advances from that screen a navigationController is loaded in with a standard background color and can advance through the next screens. Is it possible to have just one image always stay as the background, i know i can use:

`self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

to allow the background to show through, but for some reason when i do this i see the first background image(the unique one), not the one that i have added to the Navigation controller.

This is the code that i use to add a bg to the nav controller:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"v3_default_bg.png"];
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
bgView.image = img;
[appDelegate.navigationController.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];
```

My question is this, is it possible to apply a non-unique background to the navigationController.

I also tried `addSubview:` instead of `sendSubviewToBack:` but that just blocks out my content. Could anyone lend me some thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[appDelegate.navigationController.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];
```

does not add the subview to the navigationController.view. You need to add it, then send it to the back:

```
[appDelegate.navigationController.view addSubview:bgView];
[appDelegate.navigationController.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];
```

Answer (score 1):

hide the navigation bar and then put Ur view there....